# How to add a (1) text notficiation on document title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, notifications

Hi I've read here about [browser tab notifications](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-display-update-notifications-in-the-browser-tab--cms-23458)

**This is the code suggested to achieve an (1) on the browser tab every second.**

```
var count = 0;
var title = document.title;

function changeTitle() {
    count++;
    var newTitle = '(' + count + ') ' + title;
    document.title = newTitle;
}

function newUpdate() {
    update = setInterval(changeTitle, 1000);
}

var docBody  = document.getElementById('site-body');
docBody.onload = newUpdate;
```

I've tried it and do not seem to work. Can't see why.. Input?

**DEMO**
http://tutsplus.github.io/tab-notification/index.html

Comment: Try `window.onload = newUpdate;` instead of the two last lines you have currently. (Be aware, this will overwrite any other window load handlers you might have set earlier; so if you need more than this one, it might be preferable to look into a “proper” way of dealing with event handling.)

Comment: So remove the last two lines and add window.onload = newUpdate; ?

Comment: why docBody instead of window ?

Comment: window.onload did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's like in the example, script loaded within the body tags, try this one:

```
var count = 0;
var title = document.title;
var update;

function changeTitle() {
    count++;
    var newTitle = '(' + count + ') ' + title;
    document.title = newTitle;
}
(function() {
    update = setInterval(changeTitle, 1000);
})();
```

Also in your code variable update is undeclared. And you're not using it, so try delete "update".

Answer (score 1):

don't use element.onload because it's still doesn't have (load) that `Id` when you are run code,check only

```
if(docBody) newUpdate();
```